# How to get callable class objects from self.__annotations__ with __future__ annotations?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing, python-dataclasses

What is the best way to look up the class from annotations if using py3.10 `from __future__ import annotations`? Previously, `self.__annotations__[name]` would get you an object but now it returns a string. You can use `globals()` as shown but that just doesn't seem right to me. Is there a better way?

```py
@dataclass
class Person:
    height: float
    def stack(self, other: Person):
        return Person(self.height + other.height) #gymnasts
@dataclass
class Chair:
    height: float
    def stack(self, other: Chair):
        return Chair(0.6*(self.height + other.height) ) #stackable chairs
@dataclass
class Room:
    person: Person
    chair: Chair
    
    def set(self, name: str, val: float):
        # lots of complicated validation
        # factory = self.__annotations__[name] # this worked before from __future__ import annotations
        factory = globals()[self.__annotations__[name]]
        self.__setattr__(name, factory(height=val))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to access the *evaluated* `__annotations__` of a "function, method, module or class object". Notably, this is aware of basic inheritance – it merges inherited annotations and uses `globals` of the current class instead of the method's module.

```py
@dataclass
class Room:
    person: Person
    chair: Chair

    def set(self, name: str, val: float):
        factory = get_type_hints(type(self))[name]
        self.__setattr__(name, factory(height=val))
```

While `typing.get_type_hints` does some additional work over just inspecting `globals`, `__future__.annotations` inherently erases non-global information. For the uncommon case of classes defined in a `locals` scope one has to explicitly provide the namespace.

Comment: Nice. What do you mean by "`__future__.annotations` inherently erases non-global information"?

Comment: @mmdanziger The pre-``__future__.annotations`` and PEP 649 annotations capture annotations according to Python's normal scoping rules; that means they can capture types defined only inside a function, for example. ``__future__.annotations`` does not capture anything, so function-local types will go out of scope with the function; such types cannot be fetched by ``typing.get_type_hints``.